# Problem using Parametric Equation of Semicubical Parabola

Tags: parametric, curves

I've been working my way through an old A'Level maths book and am having a lot of difficulty with a problem given in the Chapter on Loci & Parametric Equations:

"Find the equation of the tangent to the curve $ay^2=x^3$ at the point $(at^2,at^3)$ and prove that, apart from one exceptional case, the tangent meets the curve again. Find the coordinates of the the point of intersection. What is the exceptional case."

I am fine up to finding the equation of the tangent: $2y = 3tx - at^3$ and the exception is when $t=0$ (both verified with the answers given at the back of the book). But I can't seem to get to a/the solution for the intersection point which expects the $x$ and $y$ coordinates to be expressed in terms of $a$ & $t$. I quickly get lost in expanding terms... I guess that I am missing a simplifying step.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}} = \frac{3at^{2}}{2at} = \frac{3t}{2}$$

Equation of tangent:
$$y-at^{3}=\frac{3t}{2} (x-at^{2})$$

Let $(as^{2},as^{3})$ be the intersection, then

\begin{align*}
  as^{3}-at^{3} &= \frac{3t}{2}(as^{2}-at^{2}) \\
  2(s^{3}-t^{3})-3t(s^{2}-t^{2}) &= 0 \\
  (s-t)[2(s^{2}+st+t^{2})-3t(s+t)] &= 0 \\
  (s-t)(2s^{2}-st-t^{2}) &= 0 \\
  (s-t)^{2}(2s+t) &= 0
\end{align*}

The double roots $s=t$ due to tangency, thus **another** intersection is given by $s=-\frac{t}{2}$,

that is $$\displaystyle 
\left( \frac{at^{2}}{4},-\frac{at^{3}}{8} \right)$$

$\fbox{except $t=0$}$.

Comment: Thanks, that's awesome. I must get more to grips with algebraic factorisation...

Comment: @ChrisJH Actually, my very first attempt was trying to solve $x$, but failed to conclude that $y$ is negative.