# Find a line which is tangent to the curve $y=x^4-4x^3$ at 2 points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, analytic-geometry, tangent-line

How can I solve this? Should I set the two points as $a^4-4a^3$ and $b^4-4b^3$?

Answer (score 6):

Suppose a line $y=mx+c$ is tangent to the curve $y=x^4-4x^3$ at two points. Then the difference between these two equations must be a quartic polynomial with two double roots:
$$x^4-4x^3-mx-c=(x-a)^2(x-b)^2$$
$$=x^4-2(a+b)x^3+(a^2+4ab+b^2)x^2-2ab(a+b)x+(ab)^2$$
Comparing coefficients, we have
$$2(a+b)=4$$
$$a^2+4ab+b^2=(a+b)^2+2ab=0$$
$$m=2ab(a+b)$$
$$c=-(ab)^2$$
The first two relations yield values for $a+b$ and $ab$:
$$a+b=\frac42=2$$
$$ab=-\frac{(a+b)^2}2=-\frac{2^2}2=-2$$
The last two relations allow $m$ and $c$ to be evaluated:
$$m=2\cdot-2\cdot2=-8$$
$$c=-(-2)^2=-4$$
Hence the line tangent to $y=x^4-4x^3$ at two points is $y=-8x-4$.

Comment: @NickLiu Tangents between a line and a curve correspond to multiple roots in the difference. Since there are two distinct tangent points, it follows that they represent at least four roots. But we are dealing with a quartic equation here, so both tangents must repesent double roots. We can therefore write the difference quartic in the form $(x-a)^2(x-b)^2$.

Comment: @NickLiu You might want to read the Wikipedia article on [multiplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_(mathematics)); also note that points where two curves intersect correspond to zeros in their difference.

Comment: @NickLiu, first think of any non-constant polynomial $f(x)$. Ask yourself when is $x$-axis tangent to its graph? Well, call that point $\alpha$. Obviously, you have $f(\alpha) = 0$, but $f'(\alpha) = 0$ as well, because for $x$-axis to be tangent to $f$, you got to have local extremum. But, that means that $\alpha$ is multiple root of $f(x)$ (too see this, write $f(x)=(x-\alpha)^kg(x)$ and then differentiate to conclude that $k>1$ if and only if $f'(\alpha) = 0$). Conversely, if $\alpha$ is a multiple root of $f$, then $x$-axis is tangent to $f$ at $\alpha$. (tbc)

Comment: Oh i know what was going on now, thank you so much.

Comment: Now, if you want to see when a line $y=ax+b$ is tangent to polynomial $f(x)$, it is equivalent to find when the $x$-axis is tangent to $f(x) - (ax+b)$ and by the above it happens when there are multiple roots of $f(x) - (ax+b)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(t,t^4-4t^3)$ be a point of contact, then

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\dot{x}}{\dot{y}} = 4t^3-12t^2$$

The equation of tangent is

$$(y-t^4+4t^3)=4t^2(t-3)(x-t)$$

Let $(s^4-4s^3,s)$ be the self-intersection of its tangent.

\begin{align*}
  (s^4-4s^3)-(t^4-4t^3) &= 4t^2(t-3)(s-t) \\
  (s^4-t^4)-4(s^3-t^3) &= 4t^2(t-3)(s-t) \\
  (s^2-t^2)(s^2+t^2)-4(s-t)(s^2+st+t^2) &= 4t^2(t-3)(s-t) \\
  (s-t)[(s+t)(s^2+t^2)-4(s^2+st+t^2)] &= 4t^2(t-3)(s-t) \\
  (s-t)[(s+t)(s^2+t^2)-4(s^2+st+t^2)-4t^2(t-3)] &= 0 \\
  (s-t)[s^3+(t-4)s^2+t(t-4)s+t^2(8-3t)] &= 0 \\
  (s-t)^2[s^2+2(t-2)s+t(3t-8)] &= 0 \\
\end{align*}

The double root $s=t$ is due to tangency, thus **another** intersections are given by $$s=2-t\pm \sqrt{2(2+2t-t^2)}$$

provided $1-\sqrt{3} \le t \le 1+\sqrt{3}$.

> The line will be a common tangent if $\Delta=0$,  that is
>   $$(s,t)=(1\pm \sqrt{3},1\mp \sqrt{3})$$

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question asked. You should find the values of $t$ for which these two remaining roots are equal.

Comment: Answer is updated.

Comment: What would the equation of the line be? I am confused as to what s and t are in this context? @NgChungTak

Comment: @NgChungTak Is it pre-calculus?

Comment: @dydxx If it's a common tangent, $s$ and $t$ are symmetric in roles.  And also  $s+t=2$, they are conjugate pair.  Say when $t=1+\sqrt{3}$, $s$ will be automatically be the conjugate of $t$, i.e. $s=1-\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: @NgChungTak Ah I see , would this method also work if it wasn't two point and just tangent at one?

Comment: @dydxx Actually, It's rather a general way when a tangent of a curve has extra intersection(s) on its own.  That's exactly the approach in [another answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1678231/problem-using-parametric-equation-of-semicubical-parabola/1679088#1679088).

Comment: @Narasimham, Um, I used calculus which is prerequisite for A-level curriculum and I think this question will be tedious for one at O-level only.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x):=x^4-4x^3.$

The tangent to the curve in $(a,f(a))$ has equation:

$$y:=g_a(x)=(4a^3-12a^2)(x-a)+a^4-4a^3$$

(Do you see why ?). Using a graphical aid and making a progressive zoom on the region of interest, by trial and error, I saw that the value of $a$ such that there is two contact points is :

$$a=2.73205...$$

I recognized there the decimals of $\sqrt{3}=1.73205...$. Thus I made the assumption that $a=1+\sqrt{3}$.

Then I computed the equation of the tangent for this particular value of $a$, which is $g_{1+\sqrt{3}}(x)=-8x-4$.

Then I checked that the function obtained by taking the difference between the equation of the curve and the equation of the tangent:

$$(x^4-4x^3)-(-8x-4)=(x^2-2x-2)^2$$

has two double roots (in $x=1\pm \sqrt{3}$.)

[image]

Comment: I have added a picture.