# Any line that intersects an ellipse in just 1 point is necessarily a tangent line.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I know that that the equation of an ellipse tangent line passing through a given point $M(x_0,y_0) \in (ellipse) $  is $$\frac{xx_0}{a^2} + \frac{yy_0}{b^2} = 1$$  but I can't prove that if a line intersects ellipse in just 1 point then it's necessarily a tangent line.

Thank you.

Comment: Calculate intersection of straight line with ellipse.  2 Solutions - if both the same, find equation of tangent at that point.

Comment: Suppose a line intersect ellipse  at points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$. the distance between these points is $\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$. Now the line can be tangent if distance is zero, this is possible only if $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1=y_2$ which means one point.

Comment: To be precise, one point of intersection implying tangency is due to convexity and closeness of ellipse.  Simple crossing (with one intersection) of a straight line and a curve is just first order of contact (e.g. a straight line parallel to the symmetrical axis of parabola).  Tangent of a semicubical parabola can cross the curve again (see my post [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1678231/problem-using-parametric-equation-of-semicubical-parabola/1679088#1679088)).

Comment: Tangency occurs if and only if the intersection with order $2$ or above.  For instance, $y=0$ has triple contact with $y=x^3$ at the origin.  Now in your case, testing the discriminant in $x$ or $y$ is good enough.